# Definition of Lebesgue measure on the Circle $X=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: measure-theory, definition, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I was given the following definition:

[image]

I feel this is not adequate and would only define Lebesgue on $[0,1]$? (Wikipedia uses a pushforard of the complex exponential) Also later I am given a proof that rotation by $\alpha$, $T:X→ X, T(x) = x+\alpha \mod 1$ is $\mu$-invariant(Lebesgue on circle), but is it enough?

[image]

This seems to treat the circle as $[0,1]$ at times which is confusingly inconsistent.

Comment: All rings of sets topologies (closed under countable union, and countable intersection => closed under countable union and finite intersection) and the circle is HOMEOmorphic to $\frac{[0,1]}{x_1\sim x_2\text{ if }x_1=x_2\text{ or }x_1=1\text{ and }x_2=0}$ which is homeomorphic again to $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$ - I can explain in more detail if you like. (post 1 of 2)

Comment: Post 2: the following theorem http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Compact-to-Hausdorff_theorem is VERY useful. Given $[0,1]$ with the usual topology and $q:[0,1]\rightarrow\frac{[0,1]}{\sim}$ and $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$ the induced map $F:\frac{[0,1]}{\sim}\rightarrow\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$ is continuous, by definition it's injective, all you have to do is show is surjectivity and use the theorem. Viola, homeomorphism

Comment: Hi @AlecTeal , I am aware of the fact that $ℝ / \mathbb{Z} ≅ [0,1]/\sim$. How does this help with the fact that the measure of a general 'interval' $[a,b]$ of the circle is not $b-a$ in general?

Comment: Well consider it as a metric on the angles, and use the "principle angle" For example the angle between two lines is AT MOST $180^\circ$. If you *measure* clockwise, once you get past 6 o-clock, you just measure anti-clockwise instead!

Comment: I'm very happy with the circle metric induced by projection of absolute value on $ℝ$. I don't think the measure i wish to define is exactly equivalent to the principle angle (which is minimal distance) because I want to be able to say that $\mu(ℝ / \mathbb{Z}) = 1$, or more generally there should be 'intervals' of length $>1/2$.

Comment: Oh right, well the metric isn't the measure, I need to go now I can be more explicit later (I'm impressed with what I did given I'm on my phone!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the definition is fine. Given an interval $[a, b]$ we have two cases. Either $b-a >=1$ and $\mu([a,b]/\sim) = \mu(X) = 1$, or $0< b-a < 1$ and $\mu([a, b]) = b-a$.

Now, you might wish that the definition treat the case of intervals of the form $[3/4, 1/4]$. To that I would pedantically say something like "do you mean an image of $[3/4, 5/4]$ or of $(-\infty, 1/4]\cup [3/4, \infty)$ or what?"

Then we get to the proof of rotational invariance. Again, I think its fine, so long as we realise that $(a, b)$ is perfectly good description of a subset of $X$ regardless of where $a$ and $b$ are compared to $0$, $1$ or any other integer.

Comment: Thanks. You made me realise my problem is not actually with these definitions but with that of an 'interval' on the circle, and its not really a problem either. :)